# Issue with array in php

Tags: php, arrays

my scenerio is:

A user want to check if the specific(client) url is present in destination url or not and I have created simple script to test the specific url in one destination url.

Here is my php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['check_url']))
{
    $client_url = $_POST['client_url'];
    $destination_url = $_POST['destination_url'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($destination_url);
    $search   = $client_url;

    if(strpos($contents,$search)== FALSE)
    {
        echo "Not Found";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Found";
    }
}
```

Here is my html script:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<label>Client URL:</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="client_url" /><br />
<label>Destination URL:</label>
<textarea value="" name="destination_url" ></textarea><br />
<button type="submit" name="check_url">Check</button>
</form>
```

The above script is working in case of single destination url but when I tried to post multiple destination url(by converting it into array) I'm getting the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents( http://learntk12.org/story.php?title=seo-link-building-service) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in "path to source file" on line 24
```

where line 24 is: `$contents[$i] = file_get_contents($arr[$i]);`

Here is my php code with array:

```
if(isset($_POST['check_url']))
{
    $client_url = $_POST['client_url'];
    $destination_url = $_POST['destination_url'];
    $destination =str_replace("\r",",",$destination_url);
    $arr = explode(",",$destination);

    $search   = $client_url;

    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
    {
        $contents[$i] = file_get_contents($arr[$i]);

        if (strpos($contents[$i], $search) === FALSE)
        {
            echo "Not Found";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Found";
        }
    }


}
```

Where am I lagging in this script?

Comment: The first codelisting has an unmatched closing `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['check_url']))
{
    $client_url = $_POST['client_url'];
    $destination_url = $_POST['destination_url'];
    $destinations = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), ',', $destination_url); // replace both types of line breaks with a comma, \r alone will not suffice
    $destinations = explode(',', $destinations); // split at commas

    foreach ($destinations as $destination) // loop through each item in array
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents($destination); // get contents of URL

        echo (FALSE === strpos($contents, $client_url)) // check if remote data contains URL
            ? 'Not Found' // echo if TRUE of above expression
            : 'Found'; // echo if FALSE of above expression
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks cryptic, got it. can you please explain me how this script works

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you don't have an array $contents. It should work like this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($arr[$i]);
if (strpos($contents, $search) === FALSE) {
   echo "Not Found";
} else {
   echo "Found";
}
```